# Split detail view in seperate content areas

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

How can I split the detail view in seperate content areas?

I configured 2 content areas as backend layouts:

```
backend_layout {
    colCount = 1
    rowCount = 2
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = News-Head
                    colPos = 0
                }
            }
        }
        2 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = News without Head
                    colPos = 22
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and 1 News layout for the single view with head only:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
    20 = Detail (Head only)
}
```

after that I inserted the 2 plugins in his associated content areas and select the news layout 20 on a single plugin.

Now I inserted a switch inside the Fluid template detail.html

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 20">
    <f:then>
        <h1>
            <f:if condition="{newsItem.alternativeTitle}">
                <f:then>
                    <n:titleTag>
                        <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{newsItem.alternativeTitle}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
                    </n:titleTag>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <n:titleTag>
                        <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{newsItem.title}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
                    </n:titleTag>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
        </h1>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div class="news news-single">
            <div class="article" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                <div class="news-col">
                    <n:renderMedia news="{newsItem}" imgClass="img-responsive" videoClass="video-wrapper" audioClass="audio-wrapper">
                        <f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.media, settings:settings}" />
                    </n:renderMedia>
                </div>
                <div class="news-col">
                    <f:format.html>{newsItem.bodytext}</f:format.html>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

But only the output of else branch works. Why?
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I think you should start inspecting the value of {settings.templateLayout}

Comment: I got 2 debug outputs. 1. empty and 2. is '20' so It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault! I totally forgot to pass-through my page variable **content_news_single** from my main fluid template to my partial.

TS setting:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    # ....
    variables{
        content_main < styles.content.get

        content_news_single < styles.content.get
        content_news_single.select.where = colPos = 22
    }
}
```

And here I forgot the definition to pass-through the variable **content_news_single**

```
<div class="page">
    <f:render partial="header" arguments="{content_border:content_border}" />
    <f:render partial="body" arguments="{content_main:content_main,content_news_single:content_news_single}" />
    <f:render partial="footer" />
</div>
```

Also I never inserted **{newsItem.title}**

```
<f:if condition="{settings.templateLayout} == 20">
    <f:then>
        <n:format.nothing>
            <n:excludeDisplayedNews newsItem="{newsItem}" />
            <f:if condition="{newsItem.alternativeTitle}">
                <f:then>
                    <n:titleTag>
                        <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{newsItem.alternativeTitle}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
                    </n:titleTag>
                </f:then>
                <f:else>
                    <n:titleTag>
                        <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{newsItem.title}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
                    </n:titleTag>
                </f:else>
            </f:if>
            <f:render partial="Detail/Opengraph" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
        </n:format.nothing>
        <h1>
            {newsItem.title}
        </h1>
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <div class="news news-single">
            <div class="article" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                <div class="news-col">
                    <n:renderMedia news="{newsItem}" imgClass="img-responsive" videoClass="video-wrapper" audioClass="audio-wrapper">
                        <f:render partial="Detail/MediaContainer" arguments="{media: newsItem.media, settings:settings}" />
                    </n:renderMedia>
                </div>
                <div class="news-col">
                    <f:format.html>{newsItem.bodytext}</f:format.html>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```